# Segmentation fault ruby 1.8.7 on db migrate in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, dbmigrate

On this command `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate`

I'm getting this error :

```
 [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

I thought of trying this but the command won't execute as it doesn't know what is rvm:

```
rvm gemset empty
rvm use 1.9.2@skateparks
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Comment: what other output is produced? have you checked the crash log?

Comment: Most likely one of your native gems (e.g. database adapter?) may have gone ga-ga. Issue `ulimit -c unlimited` before your `rake db:migrate` then open the core in `gdb` (`gdb ruby core.1234`) and issue `bt` within `gdb` to see which module (and possibly which function, too) this is happening in. Can you temporarily switch to a pure-ruby gem if the crash happens in a native gem?

Comment: Where is the migration causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that RVM really works, in your `~/.bash_profile` should be line like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

If it's not there, install it, basically this command is enough:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

You shouldn't install RVM under root account, unless you know what you're doing. See https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ for more info.

For deployment is good idea to use [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).